# Adding mandatory characters to strings when building a regex

Tags: regex

I am working on the following regex:

> ^((199)[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-8])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])**\s[0-9]?$**

So I have this regex expression, unbolded  part(first 8 characters before space) works ok. In the second portion(which will be optional), starting with a space I would like to put : or . characters mandatory (at least once).

So

```
19991019 will pass
19991019 1233 won't pass because does not include : or .
19991019 10:12:12 will passs
19991019 10.2.4 will pass
19991019123.1231.123 won't pass
19991019 aa.12.22 won't pass (because no letters are allowed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an optional pattern like this:

```
^(199[0-9]|200\d|201[0-8])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])(?:\s+(\d+(?:[.:]\d+)+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BMLEo4/1)

The `(?:\s+(\d+(?:[.:]\d+)+))?` part matches 1 or 0 sequences of:

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:[.:]\d+)+)` - a capturing group matching

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:[.:]\d+)+` - 1 or more sequences of `.` or `:` followed with 1 or more digits

Note you may further tune this using `{min,max}` limiting quantifiers instead of `+`. Say, to match 1 to 3 digits, you can use `\d{1,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
((199)[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-8])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01]) (?:(?:\d+(?:\.|:|$)){1,4})?
```

The last part will accept the pattern {digits}{dot/colon/end of string} 4 times (you can adjust it).

Also I would like to mention that I don't know overall use cases (tested for the mentioned ones) and it may need some tweaks.